# How can I use > and < operation in zf2 doctrine custom repository

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to run

```
$qry = $qb2->where("n2.userFk!=0 AND n2.id >1 <20")
```

in doctrine repository but it is not working. It is giving error for `>` and `<`  operators.

Comment: You would need to add the field name for the 'greater than' condition: `n2.userFk != 0 AND n2.id > 1 AND n2.id < 20`

Answer (score 0):

Use [expressions](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html):

```
$expr = $qb2->expr();
$qry = $qb2->andWhere(
    $expr->neq('n2.userFK', 0)
    $expr->andX(
        $expr->gt('n2.id', 1),
        $expr->lt('n2.id', 20)
    )
);
```